# Is it possible to get metadata from pdf file using php/ jsp

Tags: php, pdf, metadata

Actually I'm trying to get the date of creation, author, title, last modified date etc from pdf which will be uploaded to the server and then store these metadata value into the database. Is there any simple implementation to do it which will be applicable for all pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Zend_pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.info.html) Framework:

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($pdfFilePath);

echo $pdf->properties['Title'] . "\n";
echo $pdf->properties['Author'] . "\n";
```

Limitation: Works only on unencrypted files smaller than 16MB.

Comment: @ Akshat
Thanks. Can you share some video tutorials ?